# Polymer 1.0 iron-ajax call is made but on-response does not fire and the data isn't bound

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have the following code

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />


<dom-module id="custom-Element">
    <iron-ajax auto
               url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast"
               params='{"q":"California"}'
               handle-as="json"
               on-response="handleResponse"
               last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
    <span>{{ajaxResponse.city.name}}</span>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'custom-Element',
            handleResponse: function ()
            {
                console.log('  blalba');
            },
            ready: function () {
                setInterval(function () { console.log(this.ajaxResponse); }, 1000);

            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

My problem is even though the ajax call is happening and data is retrieved the on-response "handleResponse" method is never being fired and the "ajaxResponse" isn't being populated either. I tried looking at different tutorials and code demos but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code.

Comment: shot in the dark -- try putting it inside a template (<template><iron-ajax auto ..... ><span>{{ajaxResponse.city.name}}</span></template>)  -- check this vid tuturial regarding iron-ajax if you want -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDRCV8TzJZY

Comment: wow that's correct. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yea, all dom-modules must have a `<template>` tag. @tasos you should create an answer.

Comment: Yes please Tasos create a response.

Comment: @ mbunit @rzvme --  ok will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `<dom-module` The iron-ajax or anything else needs to go inside a `<template` as its placed in the shadow dom.

**eg**

```
<dom-module id="custom-Element">
    <template>
    <iron-ajax auto ..... >
    <span>{{ajaxResponse.city.name}}</span>
    </template>
..
...
.....
</dom-module>
```

Ill explain a bit further.

Because you are creating a dom-module `custom-Element` and you are calling it with `<custom-Element></custom-element>` to display the data anything inside `dom-module` needs to be inside a `<template></template>` so its placed in the shadow dom and registers the id name `custom-Element`.

Think of the html5 `<video>` tag

Now by doing

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

it will play a video.

However when you inspect `<video>` you cant see any special css like for the play /stop pause  buttons or any javascript because its placed in the Shadow Dom of the browser and its hidden away.

So the `video` tag its just a name build in the browser so you can use to play videos. To put that in the shadow dom you need a `<template>`

With polymer you do the same

```
<dom-module id="any-name">

<template>
...
</template>

</dom-module>
```

and to use it

```
<any-name></any-name>
```

same like the `<video></video>` tag in html5.

Good article here to read about [web components](https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/) and why templates are used