# Polymer 1.0 iron-ajax call is not made

Tags: polymer-1.0

according to this question ([Polymer 1.0 iron-ajax call is made but on-response does not fire and the data isn't bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499476/polymer-1-0-iron-ajax-call-is-made-but-on-response-does-not-fire-and-the-data-is))
I have a similar problem when I try to use my element. but the iron-ajax element is inside of the template tag.
Ironically my custom element work's, when I use 'polyserve' and I can see in the console log that my function for handling the response is executetd.
This does not happen, when I include my element e.g. in the starter-kit-app after adding it to elements.html and including it to index.html.
The 'auto' attribute for iron-ajax is set.

Why is the ajax request executed when using 'polyserve', but apparently not when using it in my app while serving with a simple http-server (python -m SimpleHTTPServer)? Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

Comment: polyserve correctly adjusts paths to your bower_components dependencies resolve correctly when creating a reusable element. You can use the http-server for your app. Can you post code? I'd say it's a missing import but don't know for sure from what you describe.

Comment: Hi @ebidel, you can find some code here --> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1k35p6m/).

Comment: You have a typo. `<dom-module id="endpoints-list" is="dom-bind">` should be `<dom-module id="endpoint-list">`. Note the removal of `is="dom-bind"` as well.

Comment: Thank you Eric. That did the trick (typo). Also I thought `is="dom-bind"` is required for auto-binding, but I found this in the documentation: "All of the features in dom-bind are already available inside a Polymer element. Auto-binding templates should only be used outside of a Polymer element."